# highlight cell based on column header and date format

Tags: vba, excel, highlight

Data
[image: Data]

Purpose is  to highlight the non date cell based on column header.
(highlight the screenshot cell C3,c5,D2,D6)

The below code I try to work for the purpose but fail.
Could please help to see what i can change?

```
Sub colortest()
    Dim MyPage As Range, currentCell As Range

    With Sheets(2).Rows(1)
        Set t = .Find("Cut Date", lookat:=xlPart)
        Set A = Columns(t.Column).EntireColumn

        For Each currentCell In A
            If Not IsEmpty(currentCell) Then
                Select Case Not IsDate(currentCell.Value)
                    Case 1
                        currentCell.Interior.Color = 56231
                End Select
            End If
        Next currentCell
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Purpose is to highlight the non date cell based on column header.
>   (highlight the screenshot cell C3,c5,D2,D6)

this would do that:

```
Sub colortest()
    Dim currentCell As Range, f As Range
    Dim fAddress As String

    With Sheets(2).Rows(1)
        Set f = .Find(what:="Date", lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            fAddress = f.Address
            Do
                With Intersect(f.EntireColumn, .Parent.UsedRange)
                    For Each currentCell In .Resize(.Rows.count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
                        If Not IsDate(currentCell.Value) Then currentCell.Interior.Color = 56231
                    Next
                End With
                Set f = .FindNext(f)
            Loop While f.Address <> fAddress
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Or

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub colortest()
    Dim MyPage As Range, currentCell As Range, t As Range, findString As String
    findString = "Date"

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

        Set t = .Rows(1).Find(findString, LookAt:=xlPart)

        Dim currMatch As Long

        For currMatch = 1 To WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Rows(1).Cells, "*" & findString & "*")

            Set t = Rows(1).Find(What:=findString, After:=t, _
                                 LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                 SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

            If t Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

            For Each currentCell In Intersect(.Columns(t.Column), .UsedRange.Resize(.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1, .UsedRange.Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0))
                If Not IsEmpty(currentCell) And Not IsDate(currentCell.Value) Then currentCell.Interior.Color = 56231
            Next currentCell

        Next currMatch
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: how would this code _"highlight the screenshot cell C3,c5,D2,D6"_ ?

Comment: assumed they made a mistake as they are searching by header and their original code worked on a one column basis.  I have added an edit that also covers this scenario.

Comment: the OP's question was quite clear to me _"Purpose is to highlight the non date cell based on column header. (highlight the screenshot cell C3,c5,D2,D6)"_,  the screenshot headers have more than one "Date" occurrence and finally OP said _"The below code I try to work for the purpose but fail"_.  he must have been _very_ mistaken

Comment: But only one Cut Date header which is what they were searching for. So based on Header there is only one match not two.

Comment: since OP's accepted your answer, it _must_ be the right one

Comment: Looks like the objective was mis-stated and you wanted to find each header with "Date" in and not simply the specified header i.e. .Find("Cut Date"  I have updated for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested)

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ColorTest1()
    Dim ur As Range, hdrRow As Range, hdr As Range, dtCol As Range, cel As Range

    Set ur = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).UsedRange

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set hdrRow = ur.Rows(1)
    For Each hdr In hdrRow.Cells
        If InStr(1, hdr.Value2, "date", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then     '<- Date Header
            Set dtCol = ur.Columns(hdr.Column).Offset(1)            '<- Date column
            For Each cel In dtCol.Cells
                If Len(cel) > 0 Then            'If cell is not empty
                    If Not cel Is Error Then    'If not Error (#N/A, #REF!, #NUM!, etc)
                        If Not IsDate(cel) Then cel.Interior.Color = 56231
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub HighlightNonDate()
    'simple function invocations
    CheckColumn (3)
    CheckColumn (4)
End Sub

Function CheckColumn(columnNumber As Long)
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
    'loop through column, start from 2 to omit headers
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        'if cell isn't a date, then color red
        If Not IsDate(Cells(i, columnNumber)) Then
            Cells(i, columnNumber).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
    Next
End Function
```